# Custom inserter for std::copy

Tags: c++, std

Given a `std::vector` which holds objects of MyClass. How can I create another vector which holds just data of one member of MyClass using `std::copy`? I guess I would have to implement a custom `back_inserter` but I could not figure out how to do this so far.

```
struct MyClass {
   int a;
}

std::vector<MyClass> vec1;

// I could copy that to another vector of type MyClass using std::copy.
std::copy(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(); std::back_inserter(someOtherVec)

// However I want just the data of the member a, how can I do that using std::copy?
std::vector<int> vec2;
```

Comment: `std::copy` is for plain copying, without modifying the elements. `std::transform` allows you to apply a transformation to each element, and then store the output of the transformation. Which is exactly what you want. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Use `std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for that.

```
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2),
               [](const MyClass& cls) { return cls.a; });
```

(If you can't use C++11, you could make a function object yourself:

```
struct AGetter { int operator()(const MyClass& cls) const { return cls.a; } };

std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2), AGetter());
```

or use `std::tr1::bind` if you can use TR1:

```
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2),
               std::tr1::bind(&MyClass::a, std::tr1::placeholders::_1));
```

---

BTW, as @Nawaz commented below, do a `.reserve()` to prevent unnecessary reallocation during the copy.

```
vec2.reserve(vec1.size());
std::transform(...);
```

Comment: I wish I had C++11 at work.. but it can also be done w/o lambdas.

Comment: It is better to call `reserve()` on `vec2`  before using `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: You can use `std::bind` with `std::transform` to skip the whole `AGetter`.

Comment: @Flexo: `std::bind` comes with C++11.

Comment: @Nawaz OK then `boost::bind`.

Comment: No C++11 or boost => Yet another struct, right? There is no way out?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `std::transform` not `std::copy` and `std::bind` to bind to a pointer to a member variable:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
  int a;
};

int main() {
  const std::vector<foo> f = {{0},{1},{2}};
  std::vector<int> out;

  out.reserve(f.size());
  std::transform(f.begin(), f.end(), std::back_inserter(out), 
                 std::bind(&foo::a, std::placeholders::_1));

  // Print to prove it worked:
  std::copy(out.begin(), out.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

My example is C++11, but if you skip the handy vector initalization and use `boost::bind` instead this works just as well without C++11.

Comment: If you're using C++11, why not use lambda instead of `std::bind`?

Comment: For simple things I prefer the binder syntax personally. It's a shame the placeholders got their own namespace, but even with that it's less verbose than the equivalent lambda.