# Simple customized iterator with lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, iterator, containers

Suppose I have a container which contains `int`, a function that works over containers containing `Point`, and that I have a function that given some `int` gives me the corresponding `Point` it represents (imagine that I have indexed all the points in my scene in some big `std::vector<Point>`). How do I create a simple (and efficient) wrapper to use my first container without copying its content?

The code I want to type is something like that:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
double compute_area(InputIterator first, InputIterator beyond) {
    // Do stuff
}

template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
void convex_hull(InputIterator first, InputIterator beyond, OutputIterator result) {
    // Do stuff
}

struct Scene {
    std::vector<Point> vertices;

    foo(const std::vector<int> &polygon) {
        // Create a simple wraper with limited amount of mumbo-jumbo
        auto functor = [](int i) -> Point& { return vertices[polygon[i]]; });
        MagicIterator polyBegin(0, functor);
        MagicIterator polyEnd(polygon.size(), functor);
        // NOTE: I want them to act as random access iterator

        // And then use it directly
        double a = compute_area(polyBegin, polyEnd);

        // Bonus: create custom inserter similar to std::back_inserter
        std::vector<int> result;
        convex_hull(polyBegin, polyEnd, MagicInserter(result));
    }
};
```

So, as you've seen, I'm looking for something a bit generic. I thought about using lambdas as well, but I'm getting a bit mixed up on how to proceed to keep it simple and user-friendly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686815/custom-inserter-for-stdcopy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest [Boost's Transform Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html). Here's an example usage:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

struct Point { int x, y; };

template<typename It>
void compute(It begin, It end)
{
    while (begin != end) {
        begin->x = 42;
        begin->y = 42;
        ++begin;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> vertices(5);
    std::vector<int> polygon { 2, 3, 4 };

    std::function<Point&(int)> functor = [&](int i) -> Point& { return vertices[i]; };

    auto polyBegin = boost::make_transform_iterator(polygon.begin(), functor);
    auto polyEnd = boost::make_transform_iterator(polygon.end(), functor);

    compute(polyBegin, polyEnd);
    assert(vertices[2].y == 42);
}
```

I didn't quite get the part about custom `back_inserter`. If the type stored in `result` vector is the same as what the functor returns, the one from standard library will do. Otherwise you can just wrap it in `transform_iterator`, too.

Note that the functor is stored in a `std::function`. Boost relies on the functor to have a typedef `result_type` defined and lambdas don't have it.

Comment: This isn't quite what the OP asked for -- he wants to take a function `int`->`Point`, plus an `int` `index`, and turn it directly into an iterator so that dereferencing returns the `Point`, and incrementing advances the `index`.

Comment: @Yakk I understood it as if they have a vector of indices and they'll pass those indices through the functor to get references to `Point`s.

Comment: It appears they want to take the indexes into the `vector` and map them to `Point`, not a `vector` of indexes.  Look where they construct their `MagicIterator` -- they pass in `0` and `.size()`, and their `functor` takes the `int` and does something arbitrary with it.  Hmm, it does go off and do `a[b[i]]`, which is what your code does in the end.

Comment: If that's the case they can use `counting_iterator` then, no?

Comment: Yes, a `counting_iterator` fed to a `transform_iterator` would match what they asked.  But as you noticed, they are using the input `i` to iterator over a `vector`, so just using a direct `transform_iterator` on the vector might be best.

Comment: Thanks! The `transform_iterator` is exactly what I was looking for. I shall have a look into the code to see how it is implemented.

As for the second part with the `result`, the thing is that if I use it "out of the box", it's fairly easy to get the `result` as a `std::vector<Point>` (as the `convex_hull` function believe it's dealing with a container containing `Point`). However I want to retrieve the indexes of those points in the `vertices` vector (aka the value_type of `polygon.begin()` before being passed to the `transform_iterator`).

Comment: Question asking if there's a stdlib way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-boostmake-transform-iterator-in-the-standard-library

Answer (score 1):

I see two methods.  Either start with [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html), then write the "functional iterator" type.

Or, use  `boost::counting_iterator` iterator or write your own (they are pretty easy), then use [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) to map that `Index` iterator over to your `Point` iterator.

All of the above can also be written directly.  I'd write it as a random access iterator: which requires a number of `typedef`s, `++`, `--`, a number of `+=`, `-=`, `-`, `+`s, the comparisons, and `*` and `->` to be defined properly.  It is a bit of boilerplate, the `boost` libraries above just make it a touch less boilerplate (by having the boilerplate within itself).

I've written myself a version of this that takes the function type as an argument, then stores the function alongside the index.  It advances/compares/etc using the index, and dereferences using the function type.  By making the function type `std::function<blah()>` I get the type-erased version of it, and by making it a `decltype` of a lambda argument, or the type of a functor, I get a more efficient version.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the information. Can you illustrate your last sentence about how to combine `decltype` with lambdas to make your code more efficient?

Comment: @skuld Write `template<typename F, typename T>struct generator_from_index_iterator;` which takes a `F(int)->T` and produces an iterator.  Then write `template<typename F, typename T> generator_from_index_iterator<F,T> make_iterator( F const& f, int index )`, possibly replacing `T` with `decltype( std::declval<F const&>()(1) )`.