# What is the equivalent of boost::make_transform_iterator in the standard library?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iterator

When dealing with a const vector, the following doesn't work:

```
const std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("test"); // error: v cannot be modified
```

Instead, you have to initialize the vector on the same line where it is constructed. However, even with this restriction, `boost::make_transform_iterator` makes it easy to do something with another vector's elements before pushing them into v. In this example, `convert` is a unary function that returns a transformed version of an input element:

```
auto beg = boost::make_transform_iterator(args.begin(), convert);
auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(args.end(), convert);

const std::vector<const char*> vc { beg, end };
```

I've taken a look at the functions available in `<iterator>` and don't see an equivalent. Is it simply missing or is there a reason why the standard library doesn't have it?

Comment: If there was an equivalent, it would most likely be called `std::make_transform_iterator`. There's not one. There are a lot of useful things in boost (and other libraries) that aren't in the standard library.

Comment: It isn't obvious what you are trying to do. Maybe `const std::vector<std::string> v={"hello","world"};`?

Comment: @Marc No, I want `vc` to avoid being modified because it will be populated by `c_str()`, which I've read can lead to invalidated pointers if `vc` resizes or anything like that. So I'm trying to initialize it on one line compared to having to use std::transform on a second line.

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you want, I'll leave it to someone else, but a better example might help: what is the relation between `test` in your first block and `args` in the second one?

Comment: @Marc Oh I see what you mean now. The first example was just to show a compiler error for push_back into v if it's const.

Comment: Why is your first example a vector of `std::string` but your second example is a vector of `const char*`? ¶ The C-strings in `vc` can't be invalidated by resizing `vc`; they can only be invalidated by modifying the `std::string` objects from whose `c_str()` methods the C-strings were obtained, which could happen for example if the `std::string` objects are also in a vector and _that_ vector were resized.

Answer (score 11):

> **UPDATE** In response to the comments, a c++20 version has been added at the bottom

For C++11 there's always the *lambda inplace initialization trick*:

```
const auto vc = [&]{
    std::vector<const char*> tmp(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), tmp.begin(), convert);
    return tmp;
}();
```

or

```
const auto vc = [&]{
    std::vector<const char*> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(tmp), convert);
    return tmp;
}();
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baddbf3c3b249a03)**

That's said, I'd prefer the Boost Range adaptors: (also **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/361c5908eeae4ada)**)

```
const auto vc = boost::copy_range<std::vector<const char*> >(v | transformed(convert));
```

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::vector</* const */ std::string> v { "test", "goodbye" };

    auto convert = std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str);

    const auto vc = [&]{
        std::vector<const char*> tmp;
        tmp.reserve(v.size());
        std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(tmp), convert);
        return tmp;
    }();
    
    for (auto cc : vc)
        std::cout << cc << "\n";
}
```

### UPDATE: C++20 Ranges

In 2023 there are standardized range utilities similar to Boost's: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4feb9dc18b0571ec)**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const std::vector<std::string> v{"test", "goodbye"};

    auto view = std::views::transform(v, &std::string::c_str);
    std::vector<char const*> vc(view.begin(), view.end());

    for (auto cc : vc)
        std::cout << cc << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I believe that the line of code that begins ```const auto vc = boost::copy_range...``` has no relationship to the block of code that begins with the ```#include``` statements, and that the two are meant to be separate approaches, where you prefer the former. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alan Correct. The Boost Range adaptors allow you to basically say the same thing in one line

Comment: This is a solution for `vector`, but Boost's is generic. The first example uses placeholders and requires that our element type is default constructible. The second example assumes the container itself can reserve memory - `forward_list` is an example that can neither reserve nor use `back_inserter`.

Comment: @cz Trueish. Even though you can easily [generalize a bit](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8de5caec156a15d2), `forward_list` would still not work well. Which is why I expressed my preference in the answer code. These days, nearly 10 years down the road, I suppose `std::ranges` has all the tools: [`forward_list` fully supported, and more optimal behaviour across the board, no more need for `std::mem_fn` even](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b9a45359da118d2)

Comment: @cz Also updated the answer with a c++20 version of just the original code in .. [2 lines of code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4feb9dc18b0571ec) really :)