# Iterate over vector using first value of std::pair only

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, std-pair

I have a std::vector as described below:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, const char*>> matrix;
```

This vector has the following values (for e.g.): [values (as an example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiKaD.png)

These values can be access here as follows:

```
matrix[0] = [0,Hello] // pseudo code (only showing values inside)

matrix[1] = [0,Fox]  // pseudo code (only showing values inside)

matrix[2] = [1,Red]  // pseudo code (only showing values inside)
```

I am iterating through the contents of the vector read the values, by doing this:

```
    for (std::vector<std::pair<int, const char*>>::iterator it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it) 
    {
        std::pair<int, const char*> v_temp = *it;
        std::cout << v_temp.first;
        std::cout << v_temp.second;
    }
```

Now, what this is doing is iterating from the first element of vector to the end element of the vector. What I want to do, is iterate only on the first elements (i.e. int values). So, from the tabular image I have attached, this current code will loop for [ row x column ] [ 9 x 2] = 18 times. What I want it for it to iterate only 9 times [ rows ] and not consider columns at-all.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the line `std::cout << v_temp.second;`?

Comment: You might want to learn how to use some [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) tool to be able to understand control flow of your programs better

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR `boost::transform_iterator` is your friend.

Example taken from [What is the equivalent of boost::make_transform_iterator in the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073388/what-is-the-equivalent-of-boostmake-transform-iterator-in-the-standard-library):

```
// I couldn't realize how to specialize type of std::get, so I need this helper.
inline int tuple_fst(const std::tuple<int, const char*> &x) {
  return x.first;
}
...
auto beg = boost::make_transform_iterator(matrix.begin(), tuple_fst);
auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(matrix.end(), tuple_fst);
for (auto it = beg; it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

This is actually a nice question, I don't understand why it is so downvoted. You wanted something like rust's `std::iter::Map` or Haskell's `map`. Unfortunately, in C++ things get a bit more ugly if you want high level iterator functions.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to skin this particular cat. One would be to use `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"),
    [](auto const &p) { return p.first; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterates over the rows of the matrix. Element `i`of `matrix` is the "row" at index `i` (in this case a `std::pair<int, const char*>`. So if you have pushed back 9 pairs then the loop will iterate 9 times.

FYI: You can simplify your code using the [C++ feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) `auto`:

```
for(auto it = matrix.begin(); it != matrix.end(); ++it){
    auto v_temp = *it;
    std::cout << v_temp.first;
    std::cout << v_temp.second;
}
```

A further simplification is

```
for(const auto& v_temp : matrix)
{
    std::cout << v_temp.first;
    // ...
}
```

You can use the C++11 for-range based loop for any object on which the compiler can call `begin()` and `end()` on.

Comment: You can simplify it more with `for(auto& v_temp: matrix) { ... }`

Comment: @Kevin Indeed! I'll append that to the answer.