# Trying to find the minimum element of 2D vector with lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std

I'm currently trying to find the minimum element of a 2D vector. I'm trying to practice using C++11 lambda functions and figured this might be good practice, but can't seem to get it compiling.

I'm aware that I could do the following:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix = {
                                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                                {6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                {5, 6, 8, 1, 12 },
                                {1, 7, 2, 4, 18 },
};

int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
for(const auto& row : matrix)
{
  int minElemInRow = *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end());
  result = std::min(result , minElemInRow);
}
return result;
```

but was wondering if the same could be done with a lambda function. Currently, this is my best attempt:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix = {
                                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                                {6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                {5, 6, 8, 1, 12 },
                                {1, 7, 2, 4, 18 },
};

return *std::min_element(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), 
  [](const auto& row)
  {
    return *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end());
  });
```

I get the error: **error C2672**: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found

How I feel it should be working is that the outer min_element will pass in a row at a time (which is just a reference to a vector), from which I can return the smallest, which will then be compared against other rows.

I thought that the problem might be that the lambda would be receiving an iterator to a vector of ints rather than a reference to the vector of ints, but dereferencing doesn't seem to be helping.

Is there a better way to be doing what I'm trying to do?

@assembly_wizard pointed out that min_element wants a predicate which can compare two of the item passed it. That is two rows. This leads to the following code:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix = {
                                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                                {6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
                                {5, 6, 8, 1, 12 },
                                {1, 7, 2, 4, 18 },
};

auto i = std::min_element(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(),
        [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
{
        return *std::min_element(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()) <
            *std::min_element(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
});
```

This will find the row with the smallest element. Though I can make that work by wrapping it in yet another std::min_element, that's getting way more complex than to be remotely helpful. If anyone has a better suggestion, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: `min_element` accepts a comparison function, i.e. a lambda that takes two rows and says which is smaller

Comment: I see. That makes sense. So I can fix that up to find the row with the minimum element, but is there a way to just find the smallest element of a 2D vector in one line?

Comment: You can try using `std::transform` first with your lambda and then `min_element` again on the result of the transform, or `std::reduce` with calling `min_element` once inside the lambda and comparing the result yourself. I think both of these aren't as simple as you would like.

Comment: Gotcha! Yea that sounds way more complicated than I'd intended.

Comment: The problem here is that `std::transform` doesn't return an iterator. But it turns out that there is `boost::make_transform_iterator` if you can use `boost`. Otherwise, look at this trick - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089938/2566065

Comment: Oof, this seems too complicated for me, would you be willing to break it down as an answer? I'm constantly trying to learn better uses of STL, but haven't touched boost yet honestly. It's easy to be overwhelmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've compiled a working version that does what I've mentioned in the comments:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        {5, 6, 8, 1, 12 },
        {1, 7, 2, 4, 18 },
    };

    std::vector<int> row_minimums(matrix.size());
    std::transform(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), row_minimums.begin(), [](const auto& row) {
        return *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end());
    });
    auto i = *std::min_element(row_minimums.begin(), row_minimums.end());

    std::cout << "Minimum element is: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

[See it in action on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wb3aq1)

This will take the minimum of each row separately, so we get `row_minimums` which is a vector of ints, and then it takes the minimum of these to get the final result between all the rows.

The only thing making this code worse than the `for` loop version, is that it keeps all of the `row_minimums` in memory at once, before running `min_element` on them. Unfortunately I don't know of a way to do this simultaneously, but I'm not the greatest STL expect, so maybe there is a way.

Other options you might consider is first concatenating the 2D matrix into a 1D vector and then using `min_element` on it, or the option you've included in your edit where you call `min_element` 3 times.

Also, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26089938/2566065) seems to have interesting info regarding solutions using the `boost` library which might be better, but I'm not sure exactly what they are.

Comment: This is awesome :) Thanks so much! Is there a reason you choose to use transform over assignment?

Comment: Assignment to where? I mapped each row to an int, so I created a new vector with `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little simpler:
With std::for_each you iterate over each vector in matrix, and obtain the minimum element of them. As `min` is captured by reference, you get the min of all of them.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        {5, 6, 8, 1, 12 },
        {1, 7, 2, 4, 18 },
    };

    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    std::for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), 
        [&min](const auto& v) 
        { 
           min = std::min(*min_element(v.begin(), v.end()), min);
        }
    );

    std::cout << "Minimum element is: " << min << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is the solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: Love it! This looks closer to what I was trying to do!