# Copy std::vector but apply lambda to each element

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

I have got a std::vector X of std::vector of, say, double in C++.

How can I transform X into a std::vector Y of int such that X[i].size() == Y[i] holds for all admissible indices i?

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > X;
...
/* What I want to do should look as follows */
std::vector<int> Y = std::copy_and_transform( X, lambda_to_get_size );
```

Of course, this can be realized with a loop, but in C++11 we would like to use lambdas instead. I have not found anything like that in std::algorithm. The standard tools seem to only give in place transformations that change the original vector and which do not allow changing the data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom inserter for std::copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686815/custom-inserter-for-stdcopy)

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::vector<int> Y;
std::transform(X.cbegin(), X.cend(), std::back_inserter(Y), [](const std::vector<int>& value) {
    return value.size();
});
```

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c++11], so I would change `const auto` in lambda to something complicated (`decltype(X)::const_reference` or something else)

Comment: @Zereges Thanks! Explicitly writing the type also works :)

Comment: @Zereges, I disagree with that for reasons laid out by Google C++ development team here : https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#auto Stack Overflow is an educational site, and showing the full type aids clarity. I worry that `auto` is a crutch to not think about what's going on and ripe for overuse/'misuse'.

Comment: @SteveTownsend Main reason for not using `auto` for me there is because the OP tagged the question as [tag:c++11], where generic lambda is ill-formed.